# How to response data after create data "model.save()" in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try the response model after create data but it doesn't work. It shows data on "console.log" and it didn't respond when I use  "resolve({})".

In the routers.js:

```
const register = require('./functions/register');
module.exports = router => {

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.end('Welcome to Idol Fan With your Idol !'));

//======REGISTER & LOGIN WITH SOCIAL =====
router.post('/socialuser', (req, res) => {
    const social_id = req.body.social_id;
    const token = req.body.token;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const photoprofile = req.body.photoprofile;
    const tokenfirebase = req.body.tokenfirebase;

    if (!social_id) {

        res.status(400).json({message: 'Invalid Request !'});

    } else {

        register.registerUser(social_id, name, email, photoprofile, token, tokenfirebase)

            .then(result => {

                res.status(result.status).json({status: result.status, message: result.message, user: result.user})
            })

            .catch(err => res.status(err.status).json({message: err.message}));
    }
});
}
```

Function Register.js:

```
const userfan = require('../models/user');
exports.registerUser = (social_id, name, email, photoprofile, token, 
tokenfirebase) =>

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const d = new Date();
    const timeStamp = d.getTime();

    userfan.find({social_id: social_id})
        .then(users => {
            if (users.length == 0) {

                let newUser = new userfan({
                    social_id: social_id,
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    photoprofile: photoprofile,
                    token: token,
                    tokenfirebase: tokenfirebase,
                    created_at: timeStamp
                });

                newUser.save()
                    .then(doc => {
                        console.log("run... " + doc);
                        resolve({
                            status: 200,
                            message: 'User Register Sucessfully !',
                            user: doc

                        });
                    })

                    .catch(err => {
                        console.error(err)
                        if (err.code == 11000) {

                            reject({status: 409, message: 'User Already Registered !'});

                        } else {

                            reject({status: 500, message: 'Internal Server Error !'});
                        }
                    });
            } else {
                return users[0];
            }
        })
        .then(usertemp => resolve({status: 200, message: "Login Successfully !", user: usertemp}))

        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
            reject({status: 500, message: err.message});
        });
});
```

This is my result after run on server:
[image]
[image]

As a result and code above. I have a question Why "user: doc" no response?. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userfan.find.then.then` (synchronous since nothing requires waiting) is called before `newUser.save.then` (asynchronous since under the hood it waits for the DB to answer).

So both `resolve` are called, but only the first call is considered, and the first one to be called is the one using `usertemp`. And this one receives `undefined` as argument, because of the implicit `return undefined` at the end of `userfan.find.then`.

Your flow should be:

```
userfan.find().then(users => {
  if (!users.length) {
    let newUser = ...
    // explicitly return the promise, which will give the created user
    return newUser.save().then(doc => {
      // format and return the value you want
      return {user: doc, message: 'registered'};
    });
  } else {
    // another explicitly returned value, but you already have this
    return {user: users[0], message: 'login'};
  }
  // it's not possible here because we returned before it, but your code reached this point
  // and, implicitly, any function ending with no return does:
  return undefined;
// this .then receives *either* the promise from newUser.save *or* the object from the else block
}).then(structure => {
  structure.status = 200;
  return structure; // here structure is {status: 200, message: 'registered'|'login', user: document}
});
```

Also, note that using the syntax shortcut (without curly braces around the function body) for arrow functions *implies* the one-line body *is* returned:

```
singleArgument => doSomething();
// is actually *strictly* equivalent to
(singleArgument) => { return doSomething(); }
```

With these ways of writing, it's easy to lose the reflex of writing `return` when it's needed.

Comment: Ok, I understood because I have just studied so I only know the basics, thank you so much!

Comment: hi @Stock Overflaw I try your code but server not stop loop and do'nt have result? only just result in log.

Comment: Indeed I did not re-type the call to `resolve`: you can either `resolve(structure)` instead of `return structure` on the last line, or you can add another `.then` to the chain like this `.then((s) => { resolve(s); })` or directly passing the reference of the function: `.then(resolve)` (the latter is classier IMO ^^). I also did not re-type the `.catch` with its `reject` call, because there is no change to it.

Comment: Ok, I changed return in each function and it works for me. And  `.then` on the last line, it doesn't return the right structure. And final it goods code. kkk